# Matching two arrays of images by color with tags

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have two UIImageView arrays which I fill up with 18 blocks and circles

```
var myBlocks = [UIImageView]()
var myCircles = [UIImageView]()
```

So after I add my circles to the screen in a nice fashion, then my blocks overtop of them, I call a function to set the tags of the circles and block to match, if the colors match. Meaning if the block is bright red, I want to find the circle that is bright red, and tag them both 0, and so on. This line below where I set the tag is throwing the error:

> Cannot subscript a value of type '[UIImageView]' with an index of type 'UIImageView'

```
func setTags() {
    for x in myBlocks {
        for y in myCircles {
            if x.tintColor == y.tintColor {
                myBlocks[x].tag = y  //Error here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there an easier way to do this? The reason I don't tag both upon creation is because the circles are created using an array that is shuffled, being that I don't want the same colored circle and the same color block on top of each other when the game loads in.

Edit: I changed it to x.tag = y.tag and it seems better. However, I'm doing two print outs now when I tap one of my square blocks.

```
 let objectDragging = recognizer.view?.tag
 print(objectDragging)

 //and

 print("the tag of the object your touching is \(myBlocks[objectDragging!])")
```

and the log I'm getting during use is

```
Optional(13)
the tag of the object your touching is <UIImageView: 0x7f8d4ba103a0;
frame = (263 180; 100 100); opaque = NO; tintColor = 
UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0.8 0.3 0.3 1; tag = 11; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x60000005fec0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000220580>>
```

So one is saying the block is tagged 13, and one is saying 11. The 13 is what it says when I print out myBlocks[count].tag, I just don't know where the 11 is coming from in the myBlocks[objectDragging] statement.

Edit 2: Is it because (myBlocks[objectDragging!]) is referencing a different block maybe?

Comment: myBlocks[x].tag = y  change this line to x.tag = y.tag

Comment: In your edit, `let objectDragging` is an integer (Int) corresponding to the tag of the recognizer's view. But there's no guarantee that the object at `myBlocks[objectDragging]` has the same tag, unless you've sorted it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues. First, `myBlocks[x]` will raise an error because you're looping through elements, not indices. Second, `x.tag = y` raises an error because the property [tag is an Int](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622493-tag) and you're trying to assign a `UIImageView`.

```
for x in myBlocks {
   for y in myCircles {
      if x.tintColor == y.tintColor {
         x.tag = y.tag  //fix here
      }
   }
}
```

EDIT: Alternatively, if you want to loop through the indices:

```
for x in 0..<myBlocks.count {
   for y in 0..<myCircles.count {
      if myBlocks[x].tintColor == myCircles[y].tintColor {
         myBlocks[x].tag = myCircles[y].tag
      }
   }
}
```

Finally, if you want the indices and the elements, you can do:

```
for (x, block) in myBlocks.enumerated() {
   for (y, circle) in myCircles.enumerated() {
      if block.tintColor == circle.tintColor {
         myBlocks[x].tag = myCircles[y].tag
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm going to edit my original post with the issue I'm having after adding that. Though it is working better. Thank you for that.

Answer (score -1):

This line:

```
myBlocks[x].tag = y  //Error here
```

`y` is an element of `myCircles`. It is not a `tag`.

Change that line to:

```
x.tag = y.tag
```

Comment: Merely copies the comment made earlier.

Comment: @matt Why did you think that? I have load this page and run example in my xcode then back to this page and answer question! Not read comment. OK?!